# Exact comparison between two numbers with ZEROFILL

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I have a PHP script where I want to compare two numbers.

```
$usernumber = $_POST['usernumber'];

$sql = "SELECT password, isadmin, disabled FROM user WHERE usernumber = " . $usernumber .";";
```

Everything is working fine but there is one more or less cosmetic problem.

The usernumber is saved as a `DECIMAL(5,0)` with *ZEROFILL*. If I compare `1` with `00001` it is true!

But is there also a possibility to compare these two with a SQL command so it is only true if they are really the same, like `00001` and `00001`?

In addition I do not have the possibilty to save it as a other datatype because I use other functions that need a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to compare it in binary mode

in MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html

in PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: The BINARY after the WHERE is not working. But the strcmp works. But I have a question to this... Is this fast? Because I have to run through about 2000 records and that about 300 times per day.

Comment: I think is a little expensive in process, but if is only a cosmetic problem you should try this str_pad($id, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); to show with left-zero-fill (just show, no comparing). But also you can do $usernumber = str_pad($id, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); and then in mysql compare like right now

Comment: It is more or less a cosmetic problem but not in a visual way. I use this number for the login and I dont want that the user is able to login without the leading zeros. So it is not possible to add 0 in the number because than the user has the possibility to login without leading zeros. I'll use the PHP solution for now and will run some tests if it is working fine with 2000 records. But your comment helped me with another problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: but you can compare that before go to the sql query, try to compare the string length. if(strlen($_POST["usernumber"])==5) hope it's help better :)